# Minus hours and minus range hours in DateTime with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php

$one = new DateTime('2012-01-24 13:00');
$two = new DateTime('2012-01-24 06:00');
$three = new DateTime('2012-01-24 08:42');
$four = new DateTime('2012-01-24 12:00');
$five = new DateTime('2012-01-24 06:33');

$array = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);

foreach($array as $a){
   $a->modify("-7 hours");

   echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}
```

**LIVE:** http://codepad.org/JgoX3y7O

I would like show date without hours between **23:00-05:00**. If date is in this range then should be doing minus without these hours.
My example show:

```
2012-01-24 06:00
2012-01-23 23:00
2012-01-24 01:42
2012-01-24 05:00
2012-01-23 23:33
```

but should be:

```
2012-01-24 06:00
2012-01-23 17:00 
2012-01-24 19:42
2012-01-24 05:00
2012-01-23 17:33
```

**$one** and **$four** are OK, because 12:00-7:00 and 13:00-7:00 aren't in range 23:00-05:00

How can i make it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly should happen to the dates when the time is between 23:00 and 5:00?

Comment: if time is between 23:00-05:00 then doing minus date without these range.

Comment: I'm also not clear what you're trying to achieve. The code does exactly what you would expect, it subtracts 7 hours from all the given DateTime objects.

Comment: i dont want date between 23:00-05:00. If date is in this range then system should doing minus without these range (23:00-05:00)

Comment: This is the part I don't understand: "then doing minus date without these range." Can you clarify that bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According from your comments I can only guess you're tyring to "skip" a certain period of time. You should then be adding a 'penalty' for that amount of time, like:

```
foreach($array as $a){
   $a->modify("-7 hours");

   // Is the time within the 'skip period'?
   if($a->format('H') >= 23 || $a->format('H') < 5) {
       // The calculation got a time between 23:00 - 05:00, add time penalty!
       $a->modify("-6 hours");
   }

   echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm right and understanding your question, you looking for something like this:

```
foreach($array as $date){
  $date->modify("-7 hours");

  // Adding one hour, so the range is 0-6am
  if($date->modify("+1 hours")->format('H') < 6) {
    //time is within that range, so substract 8 hours
    //cause we added 1 before
    $date->modify("-8 hours");
  }

  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you want to subtract 7 hours from the date/time unless the result is in the interval 23:00-05:00, then another 6 hours should be subtracted. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 13:00'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 06:00'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 05:59'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 08:42'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 12:00'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 11:59'),
  new DateTime('2012-01-24 06:33')
);

foreach($array as $a) {
  $a->modify("-7 hours");
  if(($a->format('H') + 1) < 6) {
    $a->modify("-6 hours");
  }
  echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}
?>
```

This should output

```
2012-01-24 06:00
2012-01-23 17:00
2012-01-23 22:59
2012-01-23 19:42
2012-01-24 05:00
2012-01-24 22:59
2012-01-23 17:33
```

**EDIT**
You could also just do a one-liner in the loop

```
foreach($array as $a) {
  echo $a->modify((($a->format('H') + 1) < 6) ? '-13 hours' : '-7 hours')->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}
```